# EventListener makes Spring create all scoped beans

Tags: java, spring

I have session scoped beans and want them to listen to events. For example

```
@Component
@VaadinSessionScope
public class MyView {

    @EventListener
    public void onSearch(SearchEvent event) {
    }
}
```

The problem is if I add the `@EventListener` annotation all session scoped beans that are event listeners are created.

Is there a way to prevent creating beans and only send the event to already exisiting beans or can I register event handlers programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go for a programmatic event handler registration.

You need the ApplicationEventMulticaster that you can inject:

```
@Autowired 
ApplicationEventMulticaster applicationEventMulticaster;
```

Then I hold a reference to a dynamically created `EventListener`:

```
private ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> applicationEventApplicationListener;
```

It's important to note that the class must not implement the `ApplicationListener` interface. That's the same as annotating a method with `@EventListener` and will leed to the unwanted bean creation.

```
private ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> createApplicationEventApplicationListener() {
     return event -> onApplicationEvent(event);
}
```

In my case when the component becomes visible I add the listener and when it's not visible I remove the listener:

```
if (visible) {
    if (applicationEventApplicationListener == null) {
        applicationEventApplicationListener = createApplicationEventApplicationListener();
    }
    applicationEventMulticaster.addApplicationListener(applicationEventApplicationListener);
} else {
    if (applicationEventApplicationListener != null) {
           applicationEventMulticaster.removeApplicationListener(applicationEventApplicationListener);
    }
}
```

That finally worked for me.